# Redefining Limits of the form $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it correct or possible to redifine limits of the form 
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$ and
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}$
to obtain a solution. And if so, what is this method of solving limits called?

In example: 
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x = 0$
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$

Furthermore can the equation:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \sqrt{{x}}  e^{sin(x\pi)}$

be re-written as the following?:

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}  e^{sin(\frac{1}{x}\pi)}$

Any help would be much appreciated. As I am very curious if this is valid.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @TimThayer that's what I assume, but is there a name for solving limits in this way ?